# How can I get multiple upload stream with multer storage engine?

Tags: node.js, multer

I am making a multer storage engine which makes stream connection between client and S3 Server.

At middle of the stream, my code examine chunks and send it to S3.

I could get a file stream from node.js server. But when I request file array upload, node inspector shows only one stream. What should I do?

**Stream engine snippet**

```
CustomStreamEngine.prototype._handleFile = function _handleFile (req, file, cb) {
    // for inspect
    req.files.length    // 1 
    file;

};
```

**request controller**

```
var streamStorage = multer({
    storage: streamEngine()
});

dev.post('/rec_test', streamStorage.array('source'), (req, res, next) => {

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just published this streaming `multipart/form-data` parser on npm as [form-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-parser):

You should be able to do the following:

```
dev.post('/rec_test', async (req, res, next) => {
  // Parse request
  await parser(req, async ({ fieldType, fieldName, fieldContent }) => {
    // Log all fields
    console.log({ fieldType, fieldName, fieldContent });

    // Handle 'source' file fields
    if (fieldType === 'file' && fieldName === 'source[]') {
      // Get file info
      const { fileName, fileType, fileStream } = fieldContent;

      // Upload fileStream to S3 :-)
    }
  });
});
```

Hope it's helpful.

K

Comment: Thank you! I have not tried yet for some reason. But the approach using async / await seems to be a good practice for ES6. I will try with the form-parser ASAP.

Comment: I have the same question: with my custom storage engine I can upload one image, and retrieve the stream; but when its more than one,  only the first will show up in req.files in the body. Can't see how @kasperneist answer helps. Any advice will be welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add some logs to https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/lib/make-middleware.js to check.
Currently, I use axios on the client to send multi files to the server with multer. And I can see all files in the function 
`busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, fileStream, filename, encoding, mimetype),` but there is only one file at a time, and this function will call the _handfile function of the custom storage, so that I think it is the reason for your issue.
Hope it can help you